# NullPointerException when trying to define a custom PropertyMap

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, modelmapper

I'm using ModelMapper the following way :

I have a few converter classes that are Spring components and they register custom ModelMapper mappings

```
@Component
public class FooConverter {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public static final PropertyMap<Foo, FooModel> FOO_TO_FOO_MODEL_MAP = new PropertyMap<Foo, FooModel>() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            map().setTimeZone(source.getTimeZone().getID());
        }
    };

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        modelMapper.addMappings(FOO_TO_FOO_MODEL_MAP);
    }
}
```

But I get the following error when Spring starts because the configure function gets called and the source is null.

How is that supposed to work?

Am I using it wrong?

```
1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwConfigurationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:241)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.build(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:244)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.build(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:96)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapImpl.addMappings(TypeMapImpl.java:92)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapStore.getOrCreate(TypeMapStore.java:124)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.addMappings(ModelMapper.java:113)
    at com.agilitypr.neptune.account.api.v1.controllers.PreferenceController.getUserAccountPreferences(PreferenceController.java:63)
    at com.agilitypr.neptune.account.api.v1.controllers.PreferenceController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3559fcbb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at com.agilitypr.neptune.account.api.v1.filters.AuthorizationFilter.doAuthorize(AuthorizationFilter.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at com.agilitypr.neptune.account.api.v1.filters.AuthenticationFilter.doAuthenticate(AuthenticationFilter.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.agilitypr.neptune.account.api.v1.controllers.PreferenceController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4d3aeda.getUserAccountPreferences(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder$ExplicitMappingInterceptor.access$000(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:304)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.createAccessorProxies(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:287)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.createProxies(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:277)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.visitPropertyMap(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:266)
    at org.modelmapper.PropertyMap.configure(PropertyMap.java:386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.build(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:227)
    ... 90 more
```

The bean is declared like this and Foo and FooModel are not final

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

**Important edit**

Actually, even when I create the mapping explicitly in the function inside a main class, I get the same NullPointerException.

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    final PropertyMap<Foo, FooModel> FOO_TO_FOO_MODEL_MAP = new PropertyMap<Foo, FooModel>() {
       @Override
       protected void configure() {
           map().setTimeZone(source.getTimeZone().getID());
       }
    };

    mapper.addMappings(FOO_TO_FOO_MODEL_MAP );
}
```

}

What is wrong?

I am following the example in their [documentation](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/).

**EDIT**

Deep mapping is working with these

```
public class InnerFoo {
    private int prop3;

    public int getProp3() {
        return prop3;
    }

    public void setProp3(int prop3) {
        this.prop3 = prop3;
    }

}

public class Foo {
    private InnerFoo innerFoo;

    public InnerFoo getInnerFoo() {
        return innerFoo;
    }

    public void setInnerFoo(InnerFoo innerFoo) {
        this.innerFoo = innerFoo;
    }

}

public class FooModel {
    private int prop2;

    public int getProp2() {
        return prop2;
    }

    public void setProp2(int prop2) {
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

}
```

the problem is only with the TimeZone object so I have to use a converter, which is not ideal.

```
map().setTimeZone(source.getTimeZone().getID());


public class Foo {
    private TimeZone timeZone;
    //Setters//Getters

}

public class FooModel {
    private String timeZoneId;
    //Setters//Getters
}
```

Comment: Where is your `modelMapper` bean defined?

Comment: @Makoto The question is updated. The bean is properly defined and it is not null

Comment: Is `Foo` or `FooModel` declared as `final`?

Comment: @JanRieke No, they are not.

Comment: You said mapping works with those example classes `InnerFoo, Foo l, FooModel`. Could you add an example for `FooModel` which can not be mapped?

Comment: @HeroWanders Added. I guess the timeZone.getId() function has some logic and the basic deep mapping can't handle that. It works only in a converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is ultimately due to the fact that ModelMapper can not instantiate `TimeZone` objects (nor `LocalDateTime` etc.) at the time of configuring the mapper.

Actually you don't have to configure anything.

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

FooModel model = mapper.map(foo, FooModel.class);
System.out.println(model.getTimeZoneId()); // "Europe/Berlin" here
```

This works for me. ModelMapper found out that you want to map the `TimeZone`'s property `ID` to `FooModel`'s property `timeZoneId`.

Nevertheless, just in case you want to do that manually:
Following the docs quickly, I found the concept of [converters](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#converters).
Using a `Converter` which converts `TimeZone` to `String` you can do this:

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
TypeMap<Foo, FooModel> typeMap = mapper.createTypeMap(Foo.class, FooModel.class);
Converter<TimeZone, String> tzConverter = ctx -> ctx.getSource().getID() + "!!!";
typeMap.addMappings(map -> {
    map.using(tzConverter).map(Foo::getTimeZone, FooModel::setTimeZoneId);
});

Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

FooModel model = mapper.map(foo, FooModel.class);
System.out.println(model.getTimeZoneId()); // "Europe/Berlin!!!" here
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using a converter.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming across with the same issue: My problem was that I used PropertyMap with anonymous implementation like the documentation suggested within a spring configuration. This messed up within the ExplicitMappingBuilder. What I have now is the following:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.addMappings(new UserPropertyMap());
        return modelMapper;
    }
}
```

My UserPropertyMap looks like this:

```
public class UserPropertyMap extends PropertyMap<UserRepresentation, UserDTO> {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        map().setUserName(source.getUsername());
    }
}
```

This worked like a charm in Spring Boot 2.

Comment: Nice catch, just a shame it doesn't seems to work on Android :(

Answer (score 0):

Autowire using constructor
like

```
public FooConverter(ModelMapper modelMapper){
   this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
}
```

also make sure your ModelMapper bean has been defined in your spring config class like below:

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
}
```

Comment: Constructor-based wiring only makes the lack of a bean more obvious, but if the bean were defined and wired up properly you wouldn't be able to tell a difference between field-based and constructor-based wiring.  This is fixing a symptom.

Comment: It is always prefered to use Construtor based wiring. It makes sure injecting beans are initialized before creating the Bean for the class.

Comment: The bean is properly defined and it's not null

Comment: @SayantanMandal constructor based wiring becomes really difficult in real world!