# How to map a list to its size

Tags: java, modelmapper

In my entities I have an object Shelf with a collection of books

```
public class Shelf{
  ...
  private List<Book> books;
}
```

In my ShelfDTO I only need to have the number of books

```
public class ShelfDTO{
  ...
  private int booksNumber;
}
```

I've tried with:

```
modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Shelf, ShelfDTO>() {
        protected void configure() {
            map().setBooksNumber(source.getBooks().size());
        }
    });
```

But I got an exception when I try to start the app :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder$ExplicitMappingInterceptor.access$000(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:304) ~[modelmapper-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.createAccessorProxies(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:287) ~[modelmapper-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.createProxies(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:277) ~[modelmapper-2.3.0.jar:na]
```

Is there a way to do that with a property mapping or do I have to user a Converter?

Comment: `List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();` can perhaps prevent `NullPointerException`

Comment: I tried but it didn't. not sure about where does the nullPointer comes from

Comment: If you are not going to immediately initialize your Arraylist when you make it, it'll be null until you define it. Where is your `books = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: Are you by any chance mapping `TimeZone` object somewhere as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287450/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-define-a-custom-propertymap)?

Comment: @FailingCoder The list will contains books when I fetch the shelf from DB, if any. If not, list will be null, but even with a books = new ArrayList<>(); in the Shelf constructor, I still get same exception

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Nope, nothing like that

Comment: Forgot to mention (I've edited) but this exception happen when I try to run the app, not when the mapping occurs (as I cannot reach it obviously)

Comment: I think problem is not related to the attached code. Is this your only mapping? What happens when you comment those lines? NPE is thrown because o null interceptor in this case: https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/blob/modelmapper-parent-2.3.0/core/src/main/java/org/modelmapper/internal/ExplicitMappingBuilder.java#L287